# Kohana ORM cascade delete

Tags: kohana, kohana-orm, kohana-3.2

Is there any method in Kohana 3.2 ORM for cascade delete.I am a beginner in kohana so any one can help me in this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't in Kohana. If you really need one, you should apply it on the database level ([ON DELETE CASCADE](https://www.google.pl/search?q=on%20delete%20cascade&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t))

Answer (score 1):

To cascade deletes, override the `delete()` method in your model:

```
class Model_Alpha extends ORM
{
  protected $_has_many = array(
    'beta' => array(
      'model' => 'beta',
      'foreign_key' => 'alpha_id',
    ),
    'gamma' => array(
      'model' => 'gamma',
      'foreign_key' => 'alpha_id',
    ),
  );

  function delete()
  {
    foreach($this->beta->find_all() as $entry)
      $entry->delete();
    foreach($this->gamma->find_all() as $entry)
      $entry->delete();
    parent::delete();
  }
}
```

You can then cascade further by overriding the `delete()` method on the models you're deleting.